# error CS0117: SqliteConnection does not contain definition for CreateFile

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have create a unit test project in c# and using Sqllite to test my application that does CRUD operation with the database. I am using .Net 4.8 framework and installed the following libraries

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
MSTest.TestAdapter
MSTest.TestFramework
sqlite-net
```

I am getting error CS0117: SqliteConnection does not contain definition for CreateFile.

This is my code below

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        object value = SqliteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");

        string connectionString = "Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;";
        SqliteConnection m_dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
        m_dbConnection.Open();

        // varchar will likely be handled internally as TEXT
        // the (20) will be ignored
        // see https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples
        string sql = "Create Table highscores (name varchar(20), score int)";
        // you could also write sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS highscores ..."
        SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sql = "Insert into highscores (name, score) values ('Me', 9001)";
        command = new SqliteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        m_dbConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this: [How do I create SQLite database files in .NET core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46084560/719186)

Comment: Delete the line that contains the missing method. Opening the connection to the DB will create the file.

Comment: In my tests , there is need to create two databases . How would I name the files differently

Comment: An empty sqlite DB is just an empty file. An empty file can be created in many ways